# channel form not visible for guests in EE 2.8.1

Tags: safecracker

Got a weird one.  My channel form is not appearing appearing for guests.

I have the Channel Form settings set to allow guests posts, with the username being a member in the guests member group.

My channel form code is:

```
{exp:channel:form 
channel="testimonials" 
return="test/thankyou"
return_3="test/thankyou"
include_jquery="no"
error_handling="inline"
rules:t_first_name="required"
rules:t_last_name="required"
rules:t_email="required"
rules:t_testimonial="required"
logged_out_member_id="3"
```

Any assistance pointing me in the right direction is appreciated.  Of course, if I'm missing something obvious, definitely send me a textual dope slap!

Thanks

Peter T

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm using EE 2.8.1

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just in case you were wondering...this one was totally operator error!  Yep...me!

I had forgotten one basic thing.  When I chose the default author for guest posts, I forgot to check and make sure that the author had the ability to publish entries!  Yep.  I'm a moron!

Comment: Lol, happens to all of us.