# Channel Form page doesn't load for guests

Tags: channel-entries, safecracker, ee3, forms, entries

I'm trying to figure out how to allow guests to fill out a channel form and add entries.  Based off docs I went into channel settings and clicked on "Allow Guest Submissions" and I chose a default author (super admin email).... however when i turn those on the entire page doesn't even load for guests.

based off this [post](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/30756/channel-form-not-visible-for-guests-in-ee-2-8-1), it seems like it could be permission based... However I don't have enough reputation to comment on that post and ask where specficially am I checking for those permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally narrowed it down to the form itself… for some reason the channel form wouldn’t show entire page if I had {field:comments} which was a basic textarea. not sure if that’s a bug or not. If I manually changed that to  then the form works for guests and it still saves to that textarea field at least.  weird

Answer (score 0):

did you set the "logged_out_member_id" parameter?
https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/add-ons/channel/channel_form/index.html#logged-out-member-id

Comment: if i set that in the template, the entire page doesn't load.  I was confused though, because in the settings of the channel it has dropdown to select default author... is that the same thing or do you need both?  needless to say i tried setting both and page still doesn't load when logged out

Comment: is there specific member setting permissions I need to change or member group settings?  I tried selecting another member as default author under Channel Settings (instead of super admin) and at least the page loads... however the form still doesn't show.  Driving me nuts and I need this solved asap as we are getting ready to launch.